# How to catch 'The request could not be satisfied.' page/ bad URL

Tags: php

I am trying to detect error 403 in php. When i load the content form an URL and i have error 403, to display something else. With 404 it works, but with 403, it doesn't work. I have 2 URL links:
1) 404: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTUwODE3MDE0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNTk1MjI4MzE@._V1_SX300.jpg;
2) 403: http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTg3Njc2ODEyN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTAwMzc3NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg

I tried a lot, also with http_response_code(403) and no success...
Thanks for you help...

My code is following:

```
        <div class="poster">
                    <?php
                        $posterAll = $movie->posterUrl;

                        $file_headers=@get_headers($posterAll);
                        if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0]=='HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' || $file_headers[0]=='Not Found' || (strpos($headers[0], '403'))){
                            $exists=false;
                        }
                        else{
                            $exists=true;
                        }
                        echo $exists;

                        if ($exists) {
                            $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($posterAll));
                           echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $imageData . '">';
                       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using wrong variable name to check 403.  Change `(strpos($headers[0], '403')` to `(strpos($file_headers[0], '403')`

```
if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0]=='HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' || $file_headers[0]=='Not Found' || (strpos($file_headers[0], '403'))){
                        $exists=false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Second url is returning 503 not 403. Check network inspector in your browser. Thats why your condition will not be resolved as true.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need this two queries? `get_headers` will make one and `file_get_contents` also will make one.

Anyway [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will return false on non 200 response. You could use this false value as a mark that image exists:

```
$exists = false;
$imageData = @file_get_contents($movie->posterUrl);
if ($imageData !== false) {
    $exists = true;
    echo '<img height="300" width="300" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $imageData . '">';
}
```